# Syntax for calling a method on an object inside of map{}

Tags: perl

This line of code `my %web_events = map { $_->[1]->epoch } @events;`

throws this error:

`Can't call method "epoch" without a package or object reference`

`$_->[1]` is a `Time::Piece` object that I'm trying to call the `epoch` method on.

What is the right syntax here?

*UPDATE*

```
my @events = ();
push (@events, [ 'Blah', Time::Piece->new() ]);
my %web_events = map { $_->[1]->epoch => 1 } @events;
```

*UPDATE 2 `@events` data*

```
$VAR23 = [
           'John Manzi',
           bless( [
                    50,
                    48,
                    2,
                    28,
                    1,
                    '116',
                    0,
                    58,
                    0,
                    1456645730,
                    1
                  ], 'Time::Piece' ),
           bless( [
                    50,
                    48,
                    5,
                    28,
                    1,
                    '116',
                    0,
                    58,
                    0,
                    1456656530,
                    1
                  ], 'Time::Piece' )
         ];
$VAR24 = [
           'Christopher John',
           bless( [
                    50,
                    48,
                    0,
                    29,
                    1,
                    '116',
                    1,
                    59,
                    0,
                    1456724930,
                    1
                  ], 'Time::Piece' ),
           bless( [
                    50,
                    48,
                    3,
                    29,
                    1,
                    '116',
                    1,
                    59,
                    0,
                    1456735730,
                    1
                  ], 'Time::Piece' )
         ];
```

*UPDATE 3*

OK, I'm getting closer, it seems that the way I'm storing the object in the anonymous array is wrong. Here's some code that better reflects what I have:

```
my $t = Time::Piece->new();
my $start = $t + 3600; 
my @events = ();
push (@events, [ 'Blah', $start ]);
my %web_events = map { $_->[1]->epoch => 1 } @events;
```

Comment: The code in update 3 runs without error or warning for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `$_->[1]` is a Time::Piece object that I'm trying to call the `epoch`
>   method on.

You sure about that?

Your data would have to look like this for that to be true:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;
use Time::Piece;

my @events = (
    [0, Time::Piece->new],
    [1, Time::Piece->new],
    [2, Time::Piece->new],
    # ...
);

my @epochs = map { $_->[1]->epoch } @events;
dd(\@epochs);
```

Output:

```
[1453249703, 1453249703, 1453249703]
```

Since that code obviously works just fine, I'm guessing you have a data problem and not a syntax problem.

Also, assigning the result of `map` into a hash is probably not what you want, because it will produce a hash where the keys and values are the same "thing". Additionally, if your array has an odd number of elements, you'll receive the following warning:

> Odd number of elements in hash assignment ...

To find "[one of these things that's not like the other](http://www.sesamestreet.org/)", you could:

```
print Dumper([grep { ref($_->[1]) ne 'Time::Piece' } @events])
```

Comment: Here's how I am populating `@events`: push (@events, [ $performer, $start_time, $end_time ]);

Comment: @StevieD Can you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34889394/edit) your post to include a [mcve]? It will be impossible to troubleshoot your issue without something reproducible.

Comment: OK, added to bottom.

Comment: @StevieD: The point of creating a verifiable example is that it should display the same misbehaviour as your main code. What you have posted works just fine

Comment: Well, that's what I don't get. It seems like it should be working. I have other code but it's superfluous. This is the minimal code. I can post up part of the dumped data structure so you can see it.

Comment: OK, data posted. It's the last two elements of @events.

Comment: @StevieD That particular data looks fine, but I still think you have _some_ data that isn't fine. The error message you're getting indicates you're trying to call a method on something that isn't an object, so some value in position 1 of one of those arrayrefs isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @MattJacob, ok, please look at latest snippet at bottom. I think you can reproduce it with that, though I'm not exactly sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: @StevieD: There's no problem either with your dumped data or the new code. Maybe there's a strange entry at `$events[0]`?

Comment: @StevieD Can you run this for me? `print Dumper([grep { ref($_->[1]) ne 'Time::Piece' } @events])`

Comment: OK, yeah, there was an element with no time object. Not sure how it got in there because I thought I filtered those out.

Comment: OK, double checked my logic and I found the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I think what threw me is I didn't think this would cause a fatal error. I figured the elements with proper `Time::Piece` objects would get processed fine.